# What is the value of the line integral $\int_{|z|=2}\frac{\overline{z}}{1-z}\mathbb dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have done this two ways I know, and I keep getting zero. I tried changing to polar co-ordinates and integrating from 0 to $2\pi$ which came out as zero.

Any suggestions / confirmations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:** On $|z|=2$ we have $\overline z =4/z$. Use partial fractions.

Comment: Thank you! I can take it from here

Comment: Please accept the answer, once you're satisfied, so that the question goes off the "needs to be answered" list. :)

Comment: Answer came out as 0 again. I guess I was right. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Later in your course you'll see an elegant explanation for why the answer came out $0$.